# Access folder in which Photos stores its files

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I have photos stored in the Photos app on my iPhone. I have installed the new Photos app on my Mac, and I'm using iCloud to sync pictures between Photos on my iPhone and Photos on my Mac.

On my Mac, is it possible to access the folder in which the Photos app stores my pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Launch photos, click on the **Photos** in the top navbar. On the dropdown, click **Preferences** > **General** and click **Show in Finder**. This will open the library. On top of the show in Finder button, there is the path to where the Library is located in.

Update: As Tetsujin said, the Library folder appears as a flat file rather than a directory. So access it by Right clicking > **Show Package Contents**

Comment: Just to note that the folder itself appears to be a flat file, as you're not supposed to access the contents directly - to see inside, you need to right click & 'Show Package Contents'. I'd advise against anything other than copying photos out from there - otherwise Photos will lose track of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @Tetsujin I edited to mention that

Answer (score 0):

For Os X El Capitan Users -

- Go to Pictures directory.
- Right click on Photos Library.
- Click on show package contents.
- Go to Masters directory.